# Fetching result from a SQL query in a 2-D array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a query in my Ruby file:

```
@mastertest = connection.execute("select code_ver, date from mastertest")
```

It treats `@mastertest` like a 2-D array because, when I print the rows, I get:

```
@mastertest.each do |row|
puts row[0] : row[1]
end
```

This prints all `code_ver` and `date` from each row.

I am not able to perform any other operations on it. I cannot sort the array nor can I perform a deep copy of the array. I'm guessing it is some MySQL2 type which Ruby considers. How do I convert this to a normal 2-D array?

Comment: Couple things to try:  Use `@mastertest.class` to find out what it is.  Try using `@mastertest.to_a` to convert it to an array if it isn't already.

Comment: It would help if you told us which library(s) you're using to connect to the database engine.

Comment: I am using 'mysql' gem to connect to the database.....and I think the result is returned as a mysql result set object.

Comment: @lain That's `mysql2` gem. I have answered OP's same question once. Seems he juse didn't tried enough. The class of `@mastertest` is `Mysql2::Result`.

Comment: @halfelf : I can't find an example which shows me how to use the **@mastertest.to_a** . It would be helpful if someone can show me an example.

Comment: Why not just try that in `irb`? Read some data to a instance and use `to_a` to see what happen. Since you can do that in your source now. I guess you are able to try it in irb too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class of @mastertest is `Mysql2::Result` ; it provides only [`each` and `fields` methods](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.2.6/Mysql2/Result)

Here's an example for one way to convert the results into a 2-D array:

```
sql = "select <field1>, <field2> from <table> where <conditions>"
result_array = []

result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

index = 0 
result.each do |row|
  result_array[index] = []
  result_array[index] << row[0]
  result_array[index] << row[1]
  ...
  result_array[index] << row[n]
  ...
  index += 1
end
```